# Is it possible to download an appstore app from within a UIWebView page?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I tried putting the following link into some html loaded by UIWebView

```
<A href="itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8">The download</A>
```

But it generates an error of WebKitErrorDomain/code 101.

Is it possible to download an app from within UIWebView?

Comment: BTW the `?mt=8' on the end of the url is not needed.  You only get things like that when you are navigating manually with iTunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OpenURL`:

```
NSString* url = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

and the App Store app will open.

Comment: BTW the `?mt=8' on the end of the url is not needed.  You only get things like that when you are navigating manually with iTunes

Answer (score 0):

No. You can just let the application open the Appstore with the app to download.